# How to use DOM modifying libraries along with Angular.dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Consider integration of a Dart DOM library like [Dart HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://code.makery.ch/dart/html5-drag-and-drop/) with Angular.dart. Should it be a component? or decorator(directive)? or should one rewrite the controller to use the 3rd party DOM library as a package?

Comment: Angular.dart.ui has a drag and drop component. You can have a look how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use 2 decorators: dragGroup and dropGroup.  The value could be a string 'type' in which would link the groups together.  So you could have a service/injectable that has a map of 'String type'->(dragGroup,dropGroup).  Each decorator would inject that service and install itself's dom element into the respective dragGroup/dropGroup via the Dart HTML5 drag lib.

Whichever way it's done I think it's a cool idea.

It looks like angular ui team has some open requests for it: https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/issues/54

Hmm, looking further it looks like the idea I described is how it was implemented: https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/tree/master/lib/dragdrop